# require_once, но чтобы подгружались и стили из подключаемого документа

Tags: php, html, css

есть файл, например, index.php, хочу к нему подключить файл header.php, который находится директорией выше. Для этого использовал:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../header.php';
```

но вместе с подключаемым файлом стили и js не подключились. есть какие-нибудь варианты подргрузить файл и вместе с ним то, что подргружается в нем?

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths

Answer (score 1):

В header.php пропишите абсолютные пути до стилей и js:

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="абсолютный путь до стиля">
   <script type = "text/javascript" src = "абсолютный путь до скрипта">
```